# resolvectl ignores new VPN network adapter

Tags: dns, vpn, systemd-resolved

I have a strange problem when I connect to a company VPN with forticlient application. First, I did not know what was wrong. After spending some time, I figured out that DNS is not working as it should have. Unfortunately, I have no idea, who's fault is that. It may be FortiClient, systemd-resolved, or something else. I am using Ubuntu 22.04, which is not an official version yet, but I have doubts it will get any better until official release in a week or two.

This is output from `resolvectl` before VPN is established:

```
username@hostname:~$ resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp2s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp1s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1 2a00:ee0:d::13 2a00:ee0:e::13
        DNS Domain: --
```

After VPN is established resolvectl reports additional link called `vpn`:

```
username@hostname:~$ resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp2s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp1s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS 
DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 172.20.1.21
       DNS Servers: 172.20.1.16 172.20.1.21 2a00:ee0:d::13 2a00:ee0:e::13
        DNS Domain: company.com

Link 5 (vpn)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

As you can see additional DNS servers are added to Link 3, which should help me resolve internal names when connected to VPN. Strange thing is that when I write

```
username@hostname:~$ resolvectl query name.company.com
name.company.com: resolve call failed: 'name.company.com' not found
```

I do not get anything. If I try with nslookup like this

```
username@hostname:~$ nslookup
> server 172.20.1.16
Default server: 172.20.1.16
Address: 171.20.1.16#53
> name.company.com
Server:     172.20.1.16
Address:    172.20.1.16#53

Name:   name.company.com
Address: 172.20.38.251
```

I get the correct answer. Since this was strange I traced network traffic to see what does `nslookup` differently than `resolvectl query`.

It turned out that `nslookup` uses a VPN assigned address for the source IP when asking DNS for a name. On the other hand, `resolvectl query` uses all other addresses for source IP except the one assigned by VPN. Because of that I guess DNS server does not have the route to send back an answer correctly to my computer, or DNS queries may even not reach the newly added DNS servers.

Because of that none of the programs I need can resolve the names correctly. The result is that I cannot connect anywhere within a VPN with a domain name.

Does anybody have an idea how to make resolvectl realize there is newly assigned VPN address, and it should use it as the source IP. Should FortiClient do some additional configutation on establishing a connection? Probably not.

I tried to restart systemd-resolved after VPN is established, but it does not help. Should I restart some other service? Which one?

---

Update:
I have checked how DNS is setup in network settings, and they are correct. Without VPN the network interface wlp1s0 shows:

```
username@hostname:~$ nmcli device show wlp1s0 | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2a00:ee0:d::13
IP6.DNS[2]:                             2a00:ee0:e::13
```

After VPN is connected:

```
username@hostname:~$ nmcli device show wlp1s0 | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.20.1.16
IP4.DNS[2]:                             172.20.1.21
username@hostname:~$ nmcli device show vpn | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.20.1.16
IP4.DNS[2]:                             172.20.1.21
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many different Forticlient versions:

- v6.4.8
- v7.0.0 to v7.0.5

with no luck.

You can use:

1. OpenFortiGui:
   https://github.com/theinvisible/openfortigui
   that you have to build from scratch by having qt5 dependencies installed.
   Here you have to:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/theinvisible/openfortigui.git
$ git checkout v0.9.6
$ cd openfortigui
$ git submodule update --init
$ qmake
$ make
```

Make install target does nothing, so you have to manually copy the executable with:

```
$ sudo cp openfortigui/openfortigui /usr/bin/
```

and the launch it as sudo. Then you can add a launcher for it depending on your distro with the icon they provide.

2. FortiClient SSLVPN 4.0.2332:
   https://apt.iteas.at/

Both work, the first must be built and installed manually, while the second is ready to go, even if I've noticed that one time the tunnel closed while connection didn't.

I've tested with Fortigate v7.2.0